# Recorded data on crime rates

Tags: middle-ages, crime

Is there any online source that displays the change in world crime rates since the Middle Ages? I am also looking for attempted crime, not "successful" crime, since the rate of successful murders may be confused by the improvement of medical sciences over the years.

Comment: What do you mean by "crime"? All crime? or Murder?  There are many things that are criminal today that were not criminal then and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a figure of homicide rates from Stephen Pinker's [Better Angels of our Nature](https://books.google.com/books?id=J7ATQb6LZX0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=better%20angels%20of%20our%20nature&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMIxZqslJPbxgIVwpMeCh3zFADL#v=onepage&q=tabl&f=false):

[image]

I wouldn't worry about medical science interfering with these trends much, as doctors were as likely to hurt patients as help them until the 19th century.

Really high quality crime stats only started to be collected in the 19th century, so Pinker's measures here are about as good as we can do AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks this graph partially produces the data I was looking for. A reduction in conflict since the beginning of civilization and thus an increase in order over time. I was thinking that we started as warring tribes and eventually formed the UN. Pinker's book may be a useful read for me so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @user1894167: Oh yeah, that's almost Pinker's thesis. The book got a lot of press coverage, so you can at least read a thorough review. Glad this was useful!